# I can't change the duration of countdown in flutter :(

Tags: flutter, dart, timer, countdowntimer

I manage to find a countdown but i can't change it in the way that i want to change.
I want it to change when i press a button but i couldn't do that because i can't really acces it from another class. I tried to change the duration in the on pressed option but it didn't work.

```
class Ct extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  CtState createState() => CtState();
}

class CtState extends State<Ct> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Countdown(
        duration: Duration(seconds: 10),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Duration remaining) {
          return Text(
            '${remaining.inHours}:${remaining.inMinutes % 60}:${remaining.inSeconds % 60}',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40, fontWeight: FontWeight.w200),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You should show us what you have tried

Comment: @JideGuru ``` onPressed: () => () {
                              setState(() {
                                time=2400;
                              });
                            }, ``` I set the duration above to time i tried the change it in this way

Comment: Where is this Countdown widget from? is it a plugin? and you should paste the link in your questions

Comment: Yes it is a plugin as i said i found this and imply it to my code     https://pub.dev/packages/countdown_flutter#-readme-tab-                                   here is the link for this plugin and i am sorry i am vey new for this site

Comment: I think you should try using a timer

Answer (score 0):

Make it a stateful widget and change your duration in onPressed using setState.